# Webbrowser ajax document complete

Tags: c#, ajax

How can I fire document loaded event when loads `AJAX` request? I have app, that automatically open some links at one page. This links are `AJAX` requests. How can I find out, that first link is loaded and I may click at second link?

Event document loaded will fire when I load first page via navigate method. I want fire this event (or some else) when I load next pages via `AJAX` request.

I use web browser c# component from `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Do you have control over the page you load to webbrowser control? can you inject javascript?

Comment: Application open first page via url (navigate method), then fire pageloaded event. After that, application click on link. This link send AJAX request and change page, but I have not page loaded event yet. So I don't know when I can load next page.